# Как применить регулярное выражение к столбцу и как составить регулярное выражение?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, обработка-данных, re

Имеется фрейм данных

```
data = {'id': ['1','2','3','4'],
'правило': ['{"rule": {"поток": {"ого": ["(?:\b|^)зак|пор"], "волна": []}, "воздух": {"positive": ["(?:\b|^)забор"], "negative": ["(?:\b|^)завод"]}, "final": "один"}',\
            '{"rule": {"поток": {"ого": ["(?:\b|^)зак|пор"], "волна": []}, "воздух": {"positive": ["(?:\b|^)забор"], "negative": ["(?:\b|^)завод"]}, "final": "два"}',\
            '{"rule": {"поток": {"ого": ["(?:\b|^)зак|пор"], "волна": []}, "воздух": {"positive": ["(?:\b|^)забор"], "negative": ["(?:\b|^)завод"]}, "final": "три"}',\
            '{"rule": {"поток": {"ого": ["(?:\b|^)зак|пор"], "волна": []}, "воздух": {"positive": ["(?:\b|^)забор"], "negative": ["(?:\b|^)завод"]}, "final": "четыре"}']        
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','правило'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно с помощью регулярного выражения получить значения строк колонки `правило`, начиная от `"final"` до последней кавычки `"` и записать в новую колонку фрейма.

Как это можно сделать?

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас на самом деле в столбце `правило` __сломанные__ JSON строки?

Comment: @MaxU просто нашел в интернете и дорисовал посложнее, чтобы понять механику с регулярным выражением

Comment: если у вас нормальные (не сломанные) JSON строки, то наиболее правильным решением будет распарсить эти строки как JSON, а не регулярками. PS так у вас нормальные JSON строки или поломанные?

Comment: Только такие строки

Comment: Замените пожалуйста картинки татблицами в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = df["правило"].str.extract(r'("final":.*").*')
```

результат:

```
In [154]: res
Out[154]:
                   0
0    "final": "один"
1     "final": "два"
2     "final": "три"
3  "final": "четыре"
```

NOTE: в вашем примере "сломанные" JSON строки, у которых не хватает закрывающей фигурной скобки. Если в ваших реальных данных такой проблемы не существует, тогда более правильным будет распарсить JSON строки при помощи `json.loads` или `yaml.safe_load` и после этого обращаться к элементам словаря.